# Changing permutation number in rda anova

Tags: r, p-value, vegan, rda

I'm trying to test the overall significance of an rda model using the anova() function, but I've realized that, if I run the anova multiple times, not only does it give a different p-value every time, but it also gives different permutation numbers.

> Rfpreds<-rda(Rorders ~ Cornyield + Respiration + Nmin + logNase + logBGase + logPase, data=Rfunctions, na.action="na.omit")
>
> anova(Rfpreds)

So I wanted to see if I would get more consistent results using more permutations. I'm not super experienced at using R documentation, but my understanding was that I should be able to set the permutation number:

> anova(Rfpreds, permutations=999)

but that is resulting in an error:

> Error in match.arg(model) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here, but I certainly can't report a p-value if it's different every time I run the code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have an old version of **vegan**. Probably older than 2.2-0.

Prior to **vegan** 2.2-0 we used a lazy strategy where permutations were stopped once we were sure that permutation *p*-value was below a critical threshold (typically *p*=0.05), but in 2.2-0 we always use the same number of permutations, as given in the parameter.

You have two choices: (1) upgrade **vegan** and use the argument `permutations`, or (2) set arguments `step` and `perm.max`  to the same value giving the desired number of permutations.